# Grails async Promises

Tags: grails, asynchronous

I am trying to include asynchronous programming feature in my grails project, by [reference](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0.M1/guide/async.html) to this document, I included this import

```
  import static grails.async.Promises.*
```

but it is giving

```
  Groovy:unable to resolve class grails.async.Promises,
```

I changed my servlet version to "3.0", still error continues. Anything more(mean plugin installation) I have to do. Please help

Comment: @tim_yates you are telling that I want to use grails version 2.3 right, current I am using 2.0

Comment: [Async came in Grails 2.3 I believe](http://grails.org/news/1288035)

Comment: yes thank you, http://grails.io/post/45774038833/road-to-grails-2-3-async-support#disqus_thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async api was only [introduced since](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-async/src/main/groovy/grails/async/Promises.java#L33) Grails 2.3

You need to upgrade your grails installation to use them